# WPF window open - massive delay on new PCs, works fine on older PCs

Tags: wpf, performance

This is driving us absolutely batty.

We've been developing a WPF application for months with absolutely NO performance problems. Tried to install it on a new (as in new Windows installation) PC today and it takes nearly 5 seconds to load a new window.

The application only uses 1-3 simple, small graphics (loaded from web) on any given window, and the rest of the design is simply colored buttons and basic controls. No data loading even.

We've tried it on every major chipset and graphics card and clock speed we can get our hands on. 1.3ghz dual core to 3.5ghz quad core i7. 2gb memory to 16gb memory. SSD and spinning disk. Windows 7 and Windows 8.1.

We've tried forcing software rendering (pointless given the capability of some of these machines) and removing remote images.

All we can figure is that there's some bug fix that we don't have installed yet. We've installed everything we can through Windows Update.

WPF Performance Suite looks clean. Framerate is low, but it's a static application. No sections using software rendering.

Anyone have any thoughts for what to look at next? This is ridiculous.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a different OS between old and new?

Comment: We've tried Windows 7 Pro and Windows 8.1.

Comment: It works on any computer that's been installed "for a while" (no way to quantify). Any NEW installation of Windows (7 or 8.1) has the delay.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 has a good Performance Wizard, where you can define a methods call timing measurement. You could collect the performance data and inspect which methods do slow down the app start up. Perhaps there is something not related to WPF.

Comment: I'll take a look at that. I also just discovered that the problem is somewhere in the "InitializeComponent" call. Gonna try the old fix for a similar issue and see if it's just a hotfix that got missed.